# Error in maven project: Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence

Tags: tomcat, jpa, classnotfoundexception

We have a problem with a Maven project .
The laptop version of this project works perfectly .
But the web version gives this error in attchanment.
We use for this web application:
java 1.8
tomcat v8
mysql
jpa

http://postimg.org/delete/zcvm8eglc/

http://postimg.org/delete/y592omrf8/

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: You will need to include code and exception text inline. While posting links to source and information is fine, the links could die one day and we would need to wonder what the question was about. Also, use the code formatting button (indents the code 4 spaces) to trigger a clean look for the code you include. You should also explain the problem and what you've tried to do about it.

Comment: This is the exception text line.

lug 09, 2015 4:59:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/AgenziaViaggiJPA] threw exception [javax.servlet.Servl
etException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence

Comment: so persistence-api.jar isn't in the CLASSPATH of the app. ClassNotFoundException is pretty explanatory

Comment: Which folder should I add ?
I have to add it to the build path as external jar ?

Comment: I added persistence-api.jar in the classpath.
Some errore.